# Get a specific cell value in a Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to [modify a little script](http://www.labnol.org/?p=20884) to email myself the results of a Google Form.
The script is working in its basic form, but I can't seem to be able to retrieve the value from a cell and copy it in the subject field.

Here is what I am trying:

```
var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 2).getValues();
var subject = "Todo List: " + title;
```

The script stops working though, when I do that :)
Any idea why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this but looking at 'title' you have ...getValues() suggesting a collection of titles which you assign to a single variable what does getValues()[0] give you. Try indexing into that collection maybe..

Comment: Nope, the email notification still won't work - thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

`getValues()` will return a 2-dimensional Javascript array (so I think `getValues()[0][0]` should work); but as you are wanting to retrieve a single value from a single cell, you may as well just use getValue().

`var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();`

Comment: Unfortunately my script gets stuck when I add it. Here is the full script as it is now: https://gist.github.com/akmur/b7c5ce803122a96e65b7
If I add var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue(); it just won't work, the debugger gets stuck at the "var title" line.

Comment: I got it to do what I need by adding: subject = "Discussion: " + e.namedValues['* Project Name']; in the for loop. Not really a good solution I think, but it works