# How to return a value for a specific cell with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to return the quantity available for a specific item. The Google ss reads in from a response form, and based on the response form updates the quantity of an item - the quantityRequested. The trouble I'm running into is that it updates to the same quantity for each item. After tinkering a bit, I am now getting the result 'undefined' and I've no clue why. Anyone know how to display the new value for a specific item? I also run into an error: "You do not have permission to call setValue (line 167)" - any suggestions?

```
 function updateQuantity(){

  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory");

  //add/remove items and their quantity as necessary. Remember to edit any 'else if' statement 
  var Photoshop_2D = 5;
  var Illustrator_2D = 5;
  var Premiere_Pro = 5;
  var After_Effects = 5;
  var Photoshop_3D = 5;
  var Illustrator_3D = 5;
  var Tinkercad = 5;
  var Silhouette_Studio = 5;
  var iMovie = 5;
  var Garage_Band = 5;
  var Vinyl_Cutter = 5;
  var Printer_3D = 5;
  var Headphones = 5;
  var Microphone = 5;
  var DSLR_Camera = 5;
  var GoPro = 5;
  var Handy_Recorder = 5;
  var Boom_Mic = 5;
  var Tripod = 5;
  var Makey_Makey = 5;
  var MacBook_Air = 5;
  var iPad_Air = 5;
  var Chromebook = 5;
  var Chromecast = 5;



  //i is current row index
  for (var i = 2; i<=25; i++) {
    for (var x = 2; x<=25; x++) {

    var quantityRequest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory").getRange("H2").getValue();
    var productName = activeSheet.getRange(2, 7).getValue();
    var item = activeSheet.getRange(i, 2);


    if (productName == "Photoshop 2D" && item == "Photoshop 2D") {
      var quantity = (Photoshop_2D - quantityRequest);
      break;
    } 
  else if (productName == "Illustrator 2D" && item == "Illustrator 2D") {
    quantity = (Illustrator_2D - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }  
  else if (productName == "Premiere Pro" && item == "Premiere Pro") {
    quantity = (Premiere_Pro - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "Photoshop 3D" && item == "Photoshop 3D") {
    quantity = (Photoshop_3D - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "Illustrator 3D" && item == "Illustrator 3D") {
    quantity = (Illustrator_3D - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "Tinkercad" && item == "Tinkercad") {
    quantity = (Tinkercad - quantityRequest);
    break;
    } 
  else if (productName == "Silhouette Studio" && item == "Silhouette Studio") {
    quantity = (Silhouette_Studio - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "iMovie" && item == "iMovie") {
   quantity = (iMovie - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Garage Band" && item == "Garage Band") {
    quantity = (Garage_Band - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Vinyl Cutter" && item == "Vinyl Cutter") {
    quantity = (Vinyl_Cutter - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "3D Printer" && item == "3D Printer") {
    quantity = (Printer_3D - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "Headphones" && item == "Headphones") {
    quantity = (Headphones - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Microphone" && item == "Microphone") {
    quantity = (Microphone - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }  
  else if (productName == "DSLR Camera" && item == "DSLR Camera") {
    quantity = (DSLR_Camera - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "GoPro" && item == "GoPro") {
    quantity = (GoPro - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Handy Recorder" && item == "Handy Recorder") {
    quantity = (Handy_Recorder - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Boom Mic" && item == "Boom Mic") {
    quantity = (Boom_Mic - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Tripod" && item == "Tripod") {
    quantity = (Tripod - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Makey Makey" && item == "Makey Makey") {
    quantity = (Makey_Makey - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "MacBook Air" && item == "MacBook Air") {
    quantity = (MacBook_Air - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }
  else if (productName == "iPad Air" && item == "iPad Air") {
    quantity = (iPad_Air - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Chromebook" && item == "Chromebook") {
    quantity = (Chromebook - quantityRequest);
    break;
    }    
  else if (productName == "Chromecast" && item == "Chromecast") {
    quantity = (Chromecast - quantityRequest);
    break;
    } 
  }
  return activeSheet.getRange(x, 3).setValue(quantity);
  }
}
```

Comment: You may refer with these threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458654/script-to-return-a-value-on-a-specific-cell-if-other-cell-content-meets-criteria) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248097/get-a-specific-cell-value-in-a-google-spreadsheet-script?rq=1). Use the [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method which returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Example: `var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();`

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with these threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458654/script-to-return-a-value-on-a-specific-cell-if-other-cell-content-meets-criteria) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248097/get-a-specific-cell-value-in-a-google-spreadsheet-script?rq=1). Use the [`getValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method which returns the rectangular grid of values for this range. Example: `var title = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();`